# Android Firebase InAppMessaging with custom font/style

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

After trying to implement some custom style on my notifications provided by Firebase in-App Messaging library I have face the well where I don't see any documentation regarding how to modify the typeface of my notification.

I have already tried to do my own `FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay` following [this example](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/bc850aa4cb8298b30598bd30da661b591e784d4b/firebase-inappmessaging-display/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/inappmessaging/display/FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay.java#L79) . I can set a config over with the `BindingWrapper` to build a custom view. However I don't find a way to put a custom XML where I can edit the style by my own or a method that allow me to set an `style` or `typeface`.

Anyone have been able to make this change over their own InApp Messaging implementation? My actual goal is just change the typeface of it.